# How to render first item in flatlist to full width and remaining items in 2 columns

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

How to render data in react native flatlist to display as first item taking full width and remaining elements in single row 2 columns.

```
          Item 1
  Item 2     item3
  Item4      item5
  Item6      item7 and so on
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't really do that with a Flatlist via the renderItem prop. However, take a look at [the docs here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent) and specifically look at ListHeaderComponent. If you know that you are always going to be rendering the first item in the FlatList as a full width item, then pull it out of your data and use the ListHeaderComponent to render it. Give the rest of your data via the "data" prop, and make sure the "numColumns" prop is set to 2.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can

Add index to the render item (item, index)

When index = 0 return whatever you want with your styling.

This could be an example in **Typescript**:

```
export function ListItems(props: ItemProps) {
  const { list } = props;

  const _render = ({ item, index }: { item: ItemType; index: number }) => {
    return (<View>
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        <Text>{index}</Text> {/* print items number: 0, 1, 2, etc. */}
     </View>);
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={list}
      renderItem={_render}
      keyExtractor={(i: ItemType, index) => index.toString()}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.